# Pytest not working with upgrade to MacOS Sierra

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, macos-sierra

I recently upgraded my Mac from Mac OSX El Capitan to macOS Sierra (10.12.1). `pytest` [(link)](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/) was working just fine in the previous version of El Capitan but now it throws the following error with a version check:

```
$ python3 pytest --version
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file 'pytest': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I figured `pytest` might have gotten lost in the upgrade. So, I tried installing it again:

```
$ pip3 install -U pytest     
Requirement already up-to-date: pytest in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages
Requirement already up-to-date: py>=1.4.29 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from pytest)
```

Heck, I even removed it and installed it again (via `pip3`). No go.

Now, I've never had to add a path for python modules to my `.bash_profile` (or in my case, my `.zshrc`). To be clear, though, Python had updated my `.zprofile` with

```
# Setting PATH for Python 3.5
# The original version is saved in .zprofile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

For completeness,

```
$ which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3

$ echo $SHELL
/bin/zsh

echo $PATH
[...clipped...]:/usr/local/bin:[...clipped...]
```

I'm at a loss here. If `.zprofile` has the correct path for the packages, why doesn't `pytest` work? Does anyone know how to get `pytest` working with macOS Sierra?

**Note:** I have looked on Google and SO and I could not find a question that helped.

**EDIT:**

I forgot to mention in the original post that the standard doesn't work because I'm using two versions of python

```
$ pytest --version 
zsh: command not found: pytest
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course. Soon after I posted the question, I remembered that `pytest` needs to be invoked with the `-m` flag (via `python3`) for **modules**:

```
$ python3 -m pytest --version 
This is pytest version 3.0.5, imported from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pytest.py
```